# Issue with creating a global list from map using PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have this code where I am reading a file in `ipython` using `pyspark`. What I am trying to do is to add a piece to it which forms a list based on a particular column read from the file but when I try to execute it then the list comes out to be empty and nothing gets appended to it. My code is:

```
list1 = []

def file_read(line):

    list1.append(line[10])
    # bunch of other code which process other column indexes on `line`

inputData = sc.textFile(fileName).zipWithIndex().filter(lambda (line,rownum): rownum>0).map(lambda (line, rownum): line)

column_val = (inputData
    .map(lambda line: line.split(","))
    .filter(lambda line: len(line) >1 )
    .map(file_read))
```

WHen I execute this part of code the `list1` still comes to be empty even though there's data in `line[10]` as I am using it in other parts of the code in the same function above. It seems as if it is just not appending it to the list. How can I form the list above?

Comment: Your example is so incomplete that it's only possible to speculate. Is list1 being cleared somewhere else? Have you tried adding print statements before/after the append, printing list1 and what is being appended to it?

Comment: @barny list1 is not being cleared anywhere else. I tried to do `print line[19]` inside the function `file_read()` but nothing gets printed when I call it

Answer (score 7):

Well, it actually does append to the `list1`, problem is not to the one you're thinking about. Every variable referenced in the closures are serialized and send to the workers. It applies to `list1` as well.

Every partition receives it's own copy of the `list1`, when `file_read` is called data is appended to this copy, and when a given map phase is finished it goes out of scope and is discarded.

Not particularly elegant piece of code but you should see that it is really what is happening here:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(range(100), 5)

line1 = []

def file_read(line):
    list1.append(line)
    print len(list1)
    return line

xs = rdd.map(file_read).collect()
```

**Edit**

Spark provides two types of shared variable. [Broadcast variables](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables), which are read only from the worker perspective, and [accumulators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators-a-nameaccumlinka) which are write only from the driver perspective.

By default accumulators support only numeric variables and are intended to be used mostly as counters. It is possible to define custom accumulators though. To do that you have to extend [`AccumulatorParam`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.AccumulatorParam) class and provide custom [`zero`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.AccumulatorParam.zero) and [`addInPlace`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.AccumulatorParam.addInPlace) implementations:

```
class ListParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, v):
        return []
    def addInPlace(self, acc1, acc2):
        acc1.extend(acc2)
        return acc1
```

Next you can redefine `file_read` as follows:

```
def file_read1(line):
    global list1 # Required otherwise the next line will fail
    list1 += [line]
    return line
```

Example usage:

```
list1 = sc.accumulator([], ListParam())

rdd = sc.parallelize(range(10)).map(file_read1).collect()
list1.value
```

Even if it is possible to use accumulator like this it is probably to expensive to be used in practice and in the worst case scenario it can crash the driver. Instead you can simply use another transformation:

```
tmp = (inputData
    .map(lambda line: line.split(","))
    .filter(lambda line: len(line) >1 ))

def line_read2(line): return ... # Just a core logic

line1 = tmp.map(lambda line: line[10])
column_val = tmp.map(line_read2)
```

**Side note**:

Code you've provided doesn't do anything. Transformations in Spark are just the descriptions of what has to be done, but until you call an action data nothing is really executed.