# What is the proper way to write a custom AccumulatorParam for this task?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, databricks

Context: Working in Azure Databricks, Python programming language, Spark environment.

I have a `rdd`, and have created a `map` operation.

```py
rdd = sc.parallelize(my_collection)
mapper = rdd.map(lambda val: do_something(val))
```

Let's say the elements in this mapper are of type `Foo`. I have a global object of type `Bar` that is on the driver node, and has an internal collection of `Foo` objects that needs to be populated from the worker nodes (i.e. the elements in the `mapper`).

```py
# This is what I want to do
bar_obj = Bar()

def add_to_bar(foo_obj):
    global bar_obj
    bar_obj.add_foo(foo_obj)

mapper.foreach(add_to_bar)
```

From my understanding of the RDD Programming Guide, this won't work due to how closures work in Spark. Instead, I should use an `Accumulator` to accomplish this.

I know I'm going to need to subclass `AccumulatorParam` somehow, but I'm unsure as to what this class looks like, and how to use it in this case.

Here is a first pass I have taken:

```py
class FooAccumulator(AccumulatorParam):
  def zero(self, value):
    return value.bar
  def addInPlace(self, value1, value2):
    # bar is the parent Bar object for the value1 Foo instance
    value1.bar.add_foo(value2)
    return value1
```

But I am unsure how to proceed from here.

I'd also like to add that I have attempted to simply `.collect()` the results from the mapper, but this runs into the result set being larger than the maximally allowed memory on the driver node (~4G, when upped to 10G it functions but eventually times out).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you tried anything so far ? I myself found this piece of code:

```
    from pyspark import AccumulatorParam

class StringAccumulator(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, s):
        return s
    def addInPlace(self, s1, s2):
        return s1 + s2

accumulator = sc.accumulator("", StringAccumulator())
```

So maybe you can try to do something like this:

```
from pyspark import AccumulatorParam

class FooAccumulator(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, f):
        return []
    def addInPlace(self, acc, el):
        acc.extend(el)
        return acc

accumulator = sc.accumulator([], FooAccumulator())
```

I think this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32056445/issue-with-creating-a-global-list-from-map-using-pyspark) can be also helpful to you.

Comment: I've added an edit to the original post to show what I've currently tried, but am not having any luck with. I believe the `FooAccumulator` you supplied is similar, but does not quite align with my use case. Have a second look at my example and let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you for the relevant thread link.